# How to implement WebHooks with .NET6

Tags: c#, webhooks, .net-6.0

In .net framework they introduced [ASP.NET Webhooks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/sending-webhooks-with-asp-net-webhooks-preview/) to make implementing Webhooks nice and simple. For the life of me, I can't find this in the .NET 6 documentation.

Is this library deliberately absent and is the new best practice to build this from scratch for your own app and perhaps tie it into Azure Service Bus or a similar queuing system?

Comment: You can try https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr

Comment: I'm not sure I follow here - how does SignalR relate to creating a webhooks pub/sub model system for third party websites (e.g. Zapier) to be notified about events in my App?

Comment: I think you only need a http endpoint to receive a webhook from zapier. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-api-code

Comment: I'm not wanting to receive a webhook - I want to offer one for people to subscribe to. I was hoping there would be a NuGet package or something like ASP.NET Webhooks in .net 4.8 that would take the grunt work out of it - but it looks like I might need to implement from scratch myself like this: https://medium.com/volosoft/asp-net-core-3-1-webhook-implementation-using-pub-sub-pattern-a14032b07aab#:~:text=What%20is%20Webhook,URL%20configured%20for%20the%20Webhook

Comment: webhooks and signalr are 2 different technologies. Web hooks are supposed to be a reverse API

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for the same and managed to do below. This will meet my requirement. The below code will help you as starting point and you can customise it as per your requirement.

Create a API project which can handle API Key authorisation. . Follow [this article on code maze](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-api-key-authentication/) to add the type of authentication you want to use in the project.I used AuthorizationFilterAttribute to add authentication in the below example.

Then create a controller in your project as below as

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(AuthorizationFilterAttribute))]
[ApiController]
public class WebhookController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<WebhookController> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public WebhookController(ILogger<WebhookController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("incoming/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Receive(string id, [FromBody] object data)
    {
        try
        {
            // Parse the JSON data
            var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(data.ToString());
            // Access the data you need from json object and carry out the required action
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error in processing webhook");
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
        }
    }
}
```

You can call the webhook using https://localhost:port/api/webhook/incoming/testwebhook

You can test the webhook using postman.